# Excel: Template for every Cell in one column

Tags: excel

Is it possible to have some sort of template where a certain column (lets say F) has on every line the same function for the same line:

```
row2: F2 =C2+D2
row3: F3 =C3+D3
```

and so on.

Is that possible - AND of course my data starts on row 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type in F2 cell `=C2+D2` and then drag formula down from the bottom right the cell.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "template?"

If you just want to copy a formula down the length of a column all the way to the end (without mouse dragging), copy the first cell that holds the formula you want, then hold `CTRL+SHIFT+Down Arrow` to highlight from the active cell to the last row.  Then paste.  Jumping to the end in this fashion will greatly hasten your cell selection effort (vs. mouse drag or page down, etc).

Note that Excel 2007 has 1 million rows, so saving this formula in all of them is probably  a significant waste of disk space and processing.

Or perhaps you mean something else by "template?"